# Target Class is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm building a small REST API with Laravel 4. I'm using an HMVC scheme in the application. The issue is, when I try to call a controller for the API, PHP says that the class is not instantiable.

`Target [App\Modules\ChunkletAPI\v1\ServerController] is not instantiable.`

Here's the class itself, in v1/controllers:

```
<?php namespace App\Modules\ChunkletAPI\v1;

class ServerController extends ChunkletAPI {}
```

Which inherits from

```
<?php namespace App\Modules\ChunkletAPI\v1;

use Controller;

abstract class ChunkletAPI extends Controller {

    protected $name;

    protected function __construct() {
        $this->name = '\Model\ ' . str_replace('Controller', '', get_class($this));
    }

    public function index() {
        $n = $this->name;
        return $n::all();
    }
}
```

The routing is done by:

```
<?php namespace App\Modules\ChunkletAPI;

use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function()
{
    Route::resource('server', 'App\Modules\ChunkletAPI\v1\ServerController');
});
```

I cannot figure out what is occurring - I've tried playing around, making the parent class non-abstract, etc - and Google is no help. Any ideas?

Comment: That doesn't look like a PHP error. There's probably a constraint in Laravel (which I'm not familiar with) that's preventing its instantiation.

Comment: Hmm alright, will look into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out why. `ChunkletAPI->__construct()` had to be set as `public`, not protected. Otherwise, it looked to Laravel like a static class.

Comment: No. Actually, having the constructor non-public prevents anyone from calling `new Class`. Laravel probably also tried this. The only reason to prevent instantiating classes is if you want to create a singleton - but this pattern in most cases is an anti-pattern and should be avoided.